# Chrome: Is there a way to open a bookmark with different login credentials by demand?

Tags: google-chrome

I use AWS regularly for my work tasks.
However, I use multiple accounts of it.
For each account I need obviously to supply different credentials.

So, I log into AWS and need to supply the required account credentials.

Is there a way (maybe even an addon) with which I can click an account specific bookmark and the required credentials will be automatically filled in the login fields?

Of course this AWS problem is only an example for the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For browsers such as Chrome, the best practice (as far as I'm aware) is to segregate access based on browser **profile**, i.e., create a profile for personal usage and access and a separate profile for work-related activities, etc.  By doing so, you would only need to select the profile (which will launch in its own window) and, unless you have further security settings configured, the correct credentials that are saved to that profile for auto-fill should be applied for authentication respectively.  Since profiles can be specified via `explorer.exe` shortcuts, you can pretty much minimize additional input actions to access any one particular account.

In a more generalized context, although there are services or sites that are able to receive authentication data directly via URI components (e.g., RTSP streams, etc.), I don't *believe* that applies for cloud-based file services like AWS, G Drive, etc., though I could be mistaken.  For further reading, you may want to refer to Amazon's resources [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/auth_access_what-is-authentication.html).